# How to parse config content from text connections by using `configr` package in R

Tags: r

I would like to include the config file in the head of my script through text connections.
However, it seems `configr` could not deal with the text connection value as follows.

```
library(configr)

## set text connection
t1 <- textConnection("
[sim]
step=1000

[file]
namemap=d01,d02
dirmap=A,H,B,I
",
"r")

## Get config from text connection
b <- read.config(file=zz)
```

Thus, how could I pass the content of text connection to the `read.config`?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be possible with that package. It [checks that the file exists on disk](https://github.com/cran/configr/blob/c0043a1b2ca3a2ff0c9f80f896182f500125708a/R/read.R#L41). You could file an issue with the author to see if that's something that they might consider supporting in the future. For now it seems that you will have to write the data to a (temporary) file if you want to use that function.

Comment: Could we cheat the function? Another package `config` also did not accept text connections... I do not want to write a simple config parser by myself...

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason these package authors decided not to support connections and exclusivelt use file paths. The easiest workaround I guess is to write a temp file that gets removed when the function exits. For example

```
read_config_from_character <- function(val) {
  tmpfile <- tempfile()
  write(val, tmpfile)
  on.exit(file.remove(tmpfile))
  read.config(tmpfile)
}
```

Then you could call it like

```
configstr <- "
[sim]
step=1000

[file]
namemap=d01,d02
dirmap=A,H,B,I
"

read_config_from_character(configstr)
```